# Deployment guide for Symfony 2

Tags: symfony, web-deployment

Is there a deployment guide for Symfony 2, like [this one](http://symfony.com/legacy/doc/jobeet/1_2/en/23?orm=Doctrine) for Symfony 1? I have found some basic steps in documentation but no detailed guide. Can I follow the steps in the Symfony 1 guide when using Symfony 2? Which are the differences?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this: http://www.symfony2-checklist.com/, and it seems to be what I am looking for.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a documentation entry for deployment of an application

http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/deployment-tools.html

This is a basic document but has the most necessary steps and commands to get a symfony application up and running in production environment!

Answer (score 0):

I like to use [Capifony](http://capifony.org) to deploy Symfony2 app!

Answer (score 0):

There are several tools to choose from:

- [Capifony](http://www.capifony.org/)
- [Fabric](http://docs.fabfile.org/en/1.8/) ([article about it](http://www.craftitonline.com/2013/02/fabric-deploy-your-symfony2-app-part-i/))
- More tools are mentioned in the [official docs](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/deployment-tools.html)

To automate deployments (not only Symfony2 projects) I usually use [deployhq](http://www.deployhq.com) together with local capifony strategy.